# If all elements (barring identity) are of equal prime order then $|G|=p^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers

For a finite group $G$, if $|g|=p$ for all $g\in G$ except for $e$ , where $p$ is a prime, then $|G|=p^k$ for some integer $k$. I've been thinking how this can be proved, but so far with not much success. I think the most obvious way is to prove that there can't be subgroups of $G$ of order other than $p$, but I'm having difficulty with this.
Some hints would be much appreciated. Can one possibly use the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a theorem of Group Theory that says "if a prime $p$ divides the order of a finite group, this group has an element of order $p$". Thus, if all elements of $G$ have order $p$, then its order is a power of $p$.

Comment: This theorem is called Cauchy's Theorem, but there's no converse to this theorem, so you can't say that if there's an element of order $p$ then the order of $G$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Well you can, since the order of any element divides the order of the group. You can't normally say this implies that the order of $G$ is a power of $p$, but here the hypothesis is that every nonidentity element $g \in G$ has order $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Use Cauchy's Theorem, which states that for every prime $p$ dividing the order of a group $G$, there exists some $g \in G$ with order $p$.

Comment: How can we possibly use this theorem if we don't know what the order of $G$ is?

Comment: You want to show that $\vert G \vert = p^k$ for some $k \geq 0$, i.e. $p$ is the only prime dividing $\vert G \vert$.. So suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some other prime $\ell$ dividing $\vert G \vert$. Then apply Cauchy's theorem, noting the hypothesis that every nonidentity element $g \in G$ has order $p$.